# Assign the amounts that you won on the profitable days to the variable poker_winning_days

Tags: r

```
# Poker winnings from Monday to Friday
poker_vector <- c(140, -50, 20, -120, 240)

# Roulette winnings from Monday to Friday
roulette_vector <- c(-24, -50, 100, -350, 10)

# Give names to both 'poker_vector' and 'roulette_vector'
days_vector <- c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday")
names(roulette_vector) <- days_vector
names(poker_vector) <- days_vector

# What days of the week did you make money on poker?
selection_vector <- poker_vector > 0

# Select from poker_vector these days
poker_winning_days <-
```

I know selection_vector is part of the answer.  Just not sure where to go from there.  Thanks!

Comment: You may need `names(selection_vector)[selection_vector]`

Comment: Figured it out.  It was this poker_winning_days <- poker_vector[selection_vector]

Comment: It is always better to show expected output

Comment: Or: `poker_winning_days <- names(poker_vector)[poker_vector > 0]`

Comment: That works too.  I appreciate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP already created the `selection_vector`, we can do

```
names(selection_vector)[selection_vector]
```

NOTE: Though, it is not needed to create a separate object in the global environment, it doesn't really hurt for a vector with 7 elements.